# fullstack javascript application shared interfaces

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, koa

Previously usually used different languages for front/back end and at the moment want to try to take advantage of using js/ts on both sides -> have the key data models defined in one place for both apps. what are the best practices to do so?

would use vuejs on front-end and koajs+mongodb back-end.

was thinking about simply making such stucture as:

```
-shared
 -models
  -iuser.ts
-client
-server
```

the DB schema would mirror the interface and both apps would use the interface as DTO.

is that a correct approach? any well structured sample on github?:)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I find that structure comfortable, but I think there is no good or bad approach, from what I have seen over 10 years since I wrote my first hello world, every person have it´s own style and people who like it, they adopt it or they make their own, specially when it comes down to folder structure, for PHP there are few standards (PSR) which helps easily navigate code, autoload,... but for javascript is pretty freestyle.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a separate project that only has the models (like your structure suggests) and in both your frontend and backend you can npm install the shared library